# How to use strong_params to require a nested parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, controller, strong-parameters

I'm making a Rails app, and I'd like a controller to gracefully handle an improperly formatted request. So, ideally, the parameters hash would look like this:

```
{"user" => { "username"=>"user1212" } }
```

But if someone sends data that looks like this:

```
{"user" => "user1212" }
```

I want to be able to raise a descriptive error, preferably a ParameterMissing. Right now, my user_params method looks like this:

```
def user_params
   params.require(:user).require(:username)
end
```

But if `params.require(:user)` returns a string, as in the second example, I get a NoMethodError. I tried `params[:owner].require(:username)` but that gives a TypeError. I've tried a bunch of combinations of permit and require, but I haven't found a solution I like. Is there a nice, clean way to require that params[:user] be a hash?

Comment: Did you tried giving it like this `params.require(:user).permit(:username)`?

Comment: Yes, that raises a NoMethodError because params.require(:user) returns a string. Also, I'd like to require :username.

Answer (score 5):

require returns the parameter or raises an error if the key isn't there so to get what you want I had to do the following:

```
def user_params
   params.require(:user).require(:username)
   params.require(:user).permit(:username)
end
```

note: order is important as you want the full parameter returned i.e. your user parameter so the permit statement needs to come last.  And if you wanted some optional parameters like email you would do the following:

```
def user_params
   params.require(:user).require(:username)
   params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to raise an `ActionController::ParameterMissing` instead of the `NoMethodError`, I guess you can do something like this:

```
raise ActionController::ParameterMissing.new(:username) if params.fetch(:user).is_a?(String)
```

Comment: I was really hoping not to have to manually check every param and raise the error, since this isn't the only nested param in my code.